# How to fix an css design bug

Tags: css

I have this

[image]

And want this white arrow to disappear

[image]

I have no idea how to fix it. Because of the event change line this happens

```
/*EVENT CONTAINER*/
.fc-event-container {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

/*ARROWS*/

.fc-event-container:after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 11px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 11px solid transparent;
  border-left: 11px solid #3788d8;
  position: absolute;
  right: -1px;
  top: 1px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.fc-event-container:before {
  content: "";
  border-top: 11px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 11px solid transparent;
  border-left: 11px solid #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
  top: 1px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Without HTML its really just guessing, so if you want help, post a working example on jsfiddle, codepen, here or else where, welcome :)